# how to list out all the keys and values from users' input in python

Tags: python

I get stuck on the homework for the following question:

> Create a program that paris a student's name to his class guide. The user should be able to enter as many students as needed and then get a printout of all the students' names and grades. The output should look like this:
>
> Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):[INPUT]
>   Please give me their grade (q to quit):                                   [INPUT]
>
> [And so on...]
>
> Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): > q
>
> Okay, printing grades!
>
> Student                                            Grade
>
> Student1    A
>
> Student2    D
>
> Student3    B
>
> Student4    A

Here is what I have done so far:

```
def my_dict():

    while True:

        name=input("Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):")
        grade=input("Please give me their grade:")

        my_dict[name]=grade

        if name=='q':
            break

print("Ok, printing grades!")

print("Student\t\tGrade")

for name, grade in my_dict.items():

        print("name: {}, grade: {}'.format(name, grade))
```

I know it is not right but I don't know how to pair the name and grade and how to print out all the keys and values from user input. Please let me know if you are willing to help out! Much appreciate

Comment: You are mixing up `"` and `'` in your last line.

Comment: Your function could easily `return` the values the user entered, but the variable you use for storing them can't have the same name as the function itself.

Comment: @khelwood even worse, `my_dict` is both a function and (apparently) a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here, one is a syntax error as @khelwood noted in the comments, the other one is that `my_dict` is both a function and (apparently) a non-defined dictionary.

I also `break` before adding to the dictionary, otherwise you'll end up with `'q'` as a name in the dictionary (and the user having to input a grade of student "q").

You can define a local dictionary in the function and then return it, for example:

```
def get_dict_from_user():
    user_input = {}
    while True:
        name = input("Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):")
        if name == 'q':
            break

        # It is not clear if 'grade' means a letter grade (A-F) or a numerical grade (0-100).
        # If you want numerical grade it may be better to do convert to int so you can do 
        # calculations, such as finding the average
        grade = input("Please give me their grade:")
        user_input[name] = grade

    return user_input

grades_dict = get_dict_from_user()
print("Ok, printing grades!")
print("Student\t\tGrade")

for name, grade in grades_dict.items():
    print('name: {}, grade: {}'.format(name, grade))
```

Comment: But now `name` is undefined when you enter the loop.

Comment: @tripleee fixed

Comment: The assignment seems to want columnar output, so maybe `print('{0}\t\t{1}'.format(name, grade))`

Comment: @tripleee This is up to OP to decide. My answer shows  how to fix the actual **errors** in OPs code, not how to format the output nicely (which OP doesn't even mention) (and anyway, there are much better ways to get tabular output)

Comment: Thanks tripleee and DeepSpace! I combined both of your answers and completed this exercise with a cleaner output! Happy new year!